# Add JAVA_OPTS to jboss-eap70-openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, s2i

We use [jboss-eap70-openshift](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_middleware_for_openshift/3/html-single/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform_for_openshift/)  with s2i and openshift origin 3.4. How can I add JAVA_OPTS? I do not want to overwrite them

This solution is deprecated [Not able to set options in JAVA_OPTS in JBoss openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509140/not-able-to-set-options-in-java-opts-in-jboss-openshift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This image doesn't seem to specify the `JAVA_OPTS`, so you should be able to just edit the deployment config and add the environment variable there. It will be then respected by standard `standalone.sh` script of JBoss.

Commands to add the environment variable to a dc:

```
# list your deployment config
oc get dc 

# Set environment variable on your dc
oc set env dc/<jboss-dc> JAVA_OPTS=<your env variables>
```

---

### Update after comment

## First option

After looking into the JBoss start files, there is no easy way to do this. 
You can download the start scripts using:

```
mkdir scripts
cd scripts
oc rsync <pod>:/opt/eap/bin .
```

There you can find your message in `standalone.conf` file. The snippet is very simple, so you could just repeat the same settings in your environment variable.

```
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1303m -Xmx1303m  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.policy-permissions=true"
else
   echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
fi
```

## Second option

Another solution comes to my mind. If you check `standalone.sh` file, you can see the following lines:

```
# Read an optional running configuration file
if [ "x$RUN_CONF" = "x" ]; then
    RUN_CONF="$DIRNAME/standalone.conf"
fi
if [ -r "$RUN_CONF" ]; then
    . "$RUN_CONF"
fi
```

It means you can pass your own initialization script in which you first execute the `standalone.conf` and then read some environment variable and add it to JAVA_OPTS.

To achieve it, you need to set env variable RUN_CONF=/path/to/my/script and mount this script - easy to achieve using config maps https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/configmaps.html#configmaps-use-case-consuming-in-volumes

## Third option

Also in `standalone.sh` the `SERVER_OPTS` variable is created from arguments passed to `standalone.sh`. This variable is then later passed to starting java, so I believe you could hide your options there.

OpenShift launches `/bin/sh -c /usr/local/s2i/run` on start and this script starts

```
exec $JBOSS_HOME/bin/openshift-launch.sh
```

Unfortunately in this case the `openshift-launch.sh` would have to be replaced, since it doesn't take more parameters when it starts JBoss:

```
exec $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-openshift.xml -bmanagement 127.0.0.1 $JBOSS_HA_ARGS ${JBOSS_MESSAGING_ARGS}
```

## Summary

This image does not provide an option to extend the `JAVA_OPTS`. There are some ways around it, but the simplest way would be to duplicate the options that are already there when you pass them to OpenShift. At least until it is possible to extend it and not only override.

Comment: This was also my first idea, but this override the default JAVA_OPTS. On start: `JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: <env variables>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your solutions!

Answer (score 1):

As specified in [Openshift add java option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311471/openshift-add-java-option/46337159#46337159) , you can use `JAVA_OPTS_APPEND` environment variable