# Openshift add java option

Tags: openshift

In open shift I would like to change my yaml file to enable to do this...

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose
```

My env section currently looks like...

```
  env:
    - name: JAVA_OPTIONS
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: mule-java-options
          key: JAVA_OPTIONS
    - name: MULE_KEY
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: encryption-key
          key: ENCRYPT_KEY
    - name: JAVA_MAX_MEM_RATIO
      value: '35'
    - name: JAVA_DIAGNOSTICS
      value: 'on'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending if you use a Red Hat XPaaS image; you can use `JAVA_OPTS_APPEND` environment variable :

> The contents of JAVA_OPTS_APPEND is appended to JAVA_OPTS on startup.
>
> Example: -Dfoo=bar

Comment: What if there are more variables that needs to be added like `-Dbox=fox`?

Comment: You can add more variables by seperating them with a space like;

-Dfoo=bar -Dbox=fox -DyetAnotherVar=yetAnotherVal

Answer (score 0):

For multiple variables be like;

```
-Dfoo=bar -Dbox=fox -DyetAnotherVar=yetAnotherVal
```